# How to safely modify the active Document from a ITextViewChangedListener.TextViewChangedAsync event

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

In a VisualStudio.Extensibility Extension project (VS2022), in order to modify the currently edited Document from a Command it's enough to execute:

```
public override async Task ExecuteCommandAsync(IClientContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{        
    using var textView = await context.GetActiveTextViewAsync(cancellationToken);
    await Extensibility.Editor().EditAsync(batch =>
    {
        var doc = textView.Document.AsEditable(batch);
        ...
    }
}
```

where context.GetActiveTextViewAsync(cancellationToken) wraps a call to:

```
context.Extensibility.Editor().GetActiveTextViewAsync(context, cancellationToken);
```

If I try doing the same from a ITextViewChangedListener.TextViewChangedAsync event, I don't have access to any context; at least I didn't find any.

However I can modify the Document content by executing:

```
Task ITextViewChangedListener.TextViewChangedAsync(TextViewChangedArgs args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Extensibility.Editor().EditAsync(batch =>
    {
        var doc = args.AfterTextView.Document.AsEditable(batch);
        ...
    }
}
```

My question if it's safe modifying the Document content this way and, if not, where to find the object implementing IClientContext?